# Ruby partically override parent class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, inheritance, yield

How can I override one or more lines of code in ruby parent class?
For example: I have Rails controller class with method `create`:

```
class GenericController < ApplicationController
def create
    @resource = SomeClass.new
    if @resource.save
      ...
    else
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

And I have another controller, child of this controller

```
class ChildController < GenericController
  def create
    super do
      # HERE I WANT TO DO SOME ACTIONS BEFORE SAVE.
    end
  end
end
```

How can I achieve this? I tried this (generic controller):

```
def create
    @resource = SomeClass.new
    yield if block_given?
    if @resource.save
      ...
    end
  end
```

But what if I want to pass more than one block? For example if I want to make callbacks :after_init, :before_save, :after_save and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>   def create
>     super do
>       # HERE I WANT TO DO SOME ACTIONS BEFORE SAVE.
>     end
>   end
> ```
>
> But what if I want to pass more than one block? For example if I want
>   to make callbacks :after_init, :before_save, :after_save and so on

You need to pass the blocks to the superclass method *outside* your `create()` method:

```
class Dog < GenericController
  before_save do
    puts 'before1'
  end

  after_save do
    puts 'after1'
  end

  before_save do
    puts 'before2'
  end

  def create
    super
  end

end
```

---

```
class GenericController
  class <<self
    attr_accessor :before, :after

    def before_save(&block)
      @before << block
    end

    def after_save(&block)
      @after << block
    end
  end

  def self.inherited(subclass)
    subclass.instance_variable_set(:@before, [])
    subclass.instance_variable_set(:@after, [])
  end

  def create

    self.class.before.each do |proc|
      proc.call
    end

    puts 'saving resource...'
    #@resource.save

    self.class.after.each do |proc|
      proc.call
    end

  end

end
```

---

```
Dog.new.create

--output:--
before1
before2
saving resource...
after1
```

Comment: Okay, but what if I want to add some code After resource is created? Block will execute twice then.

Comment: Thank you =) This is what I wanted =)

Comment: @Roman, If you passed blocks with your create method: 1) You would have to call create() multiple times.  2) You would have to add a variable indicating whether the block was a *before* or *after* block.  3) The super class would have to skip the `resource.save` step `if block_given?`